# How can I save Fibonacci sequence to a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion

```
def fibonacci(n): 
    lst = []
    if n == 0:   
        return 0  
    elif n == 1:  
        return 1  
    else :  
        f = fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)
        return f

h = fibonacci(4)
```

but I wnat to get a list like this : `[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, ......]`
how to get it?

Comment: @Kasramvd, I get why this is marked as a duplicate. But, equally, it's  not obvious whether OP wants the best solution, or wants to learn how to return the results of a function applied to a range. In the latter case, `map` is the solution. Still maybe a dup, but a different one.

Comment: @jpp I think you can find answer of all those questions in mentioned dups but if the question is about *returning the results of a function applied to a range*, OP should have mentioned that in title or question body. Although, I added three duplicates that shows how much this question's been asked before.

Comment: @Kasramvd, OP may not know about `map` or `range`, so probably doesn't have the necessary vocabulary. But I do like the dup targets, they should remain :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an extremely inefficient solution, but with your current logic you can simply use `map` with `list`:

```
h = list(map(fibonacci, range(10)))

print(h)

[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def fibonacci(n):
    lst = [0, 1]
    if n == 0:
        return [0]
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        lst.append(lst[i - 1] + lst[i - 2])
    return lst

print(fibonacci(0))  # ->[0]
print(fibonacci(1))  # ->[0,1]
print(fibonacci(2))  # ->[0,1,1]
print(fibonacci(3))  # ->[0,1,1,2]
print(fibonacci(4))  # ->[0,1,1,2,3]
print(fibonacci(10)) # ->[0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55]
```

OR

if you want the `fibonacci(0)` to return `[]`

```
def fibonacci(n):
    lst = [0, 1]
    if n == 0:
        return []
    if n == 1:
        return [0]
    for i in range(2, n):
        lst.append(lst[i - 1] + lst[i - 2])
    return lst


print(fibonacci(0))  # ->[]
print(fibonacci(1))  # ->[0]
print(fibonacci(2))  # ->[0,1]
print(fibonacci(3))  # ->[0,1,1]
print(fibonacci(4))  # ->[0,1,1,2]
print(fibonacci(10)) # ->[0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34]
```

Answer (score 0):

also a possibility (will not work for `n<2` but that is an easy fix...):

```
def fib(n, lst=None):
    if lst is None:
        lst = [0, 1]
    while len(lst) < n:
        lst.append(lst[-2] + lst[-1])
    return lst
```